# vertical sliding app enyojs

Tags: javascript, css, enyo

We have this example in Enyojs sampler http://jsfiddle.net/qD3bJ/

Can we make the panels arrange vertically instead of horizontal.

{kind: "Panels", fit: true, classes: "panels-sample-sliding-panels", arrangerKind: "TopBottomArranger", wrap: false

I tried changing the arrangerKind  attribue to "topBottomArranger" but it didnt work properly.

```
{kind: "Panels", fit: true, classes: "panels-sample-sliding-panels", arrangerKind: "TopBottomArranger", wrap: false
```

TIA

Comment: I think there will be some issues with making the panels arrange vertically as the scroller is vertical as well. Will have to think about this one. Is it necessary that a scroller be a component in your panel? Otherwise something like this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/aarontam/55EzP/1/

Comment: I already had a look into the TopBottomArranger but the problem with it is , its not intuitive enough to let the user know that it needs to be pulled up to go to the next panel and also when the swipe up event occurs, the previous panel also scrolls up where in this sliding app example it stays at its place and the new panel just overlaps it. This is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying - I just posted an updated answer that should address these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick fiddle with Panels utilizing a custom `VerticalCollapsingArranger` that is a subkind of a custom `VerticalCarouselArranger`: http://jsfiddle.net/aarontam/rL89M/

I basically just changed any horizontal properties to vertical properties, but will look into integrating this with the existing arrangers so that the vertical/horizontal property can be an option instead of a separate Arranger. Feel free to continue to modify as needed or necessary!